# Android: Reading EventLog

Tags: android

I was trying to implement the EventLogTags in my application (building for API level 4)
but couldn't get it to work. Actually i am trying to listen to the "ActivityManager" Log Tag
like this

```
EventLogTags event = new EventLogTags();
EventLogTags.Description desc = event.get("ActivityManager");
Log.i(tag,desc.mTag);
```

Logging is done just to ensure i am getting the desc object properly.

But it is causing FC in the APP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/EventLogTags.html) clearly states:

> This class is deprecated. This class is no longer functional. Use EventLog instead.

Comment: But it should work devices with api level 4 (for which I am building the app)

Comment: @Anuj Tenani: Then use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "FC".